# Filtering an ordered dictionary by value after reading in using dictionary reader

Tags: python, csv, filtering

Hi I am completely new to Python.

(Ive looked at the posts I struggle a bit with dyslexia and having difficulty understanding the    solutions) - so sorry if ive missed something

I need to be able to filter a large csv file by value . I can open the file and read in the data  using dictionary reader but struggling with the filter part. Ive tried to get this to work with just a lambda function using the python filter command (but couldnt get it to work) so then tried to create a filter function but struggling to getthat to work as well.
I have included a small example format of csv data file and if somebody could help me to understand how to get this filtering by value part to work on this example file, I can change the code for a bigger file.
So for example, to filter the csv file for all rows with 'blue' (value) using the key (Name5).
Any help please ?

```
#start of program  

import csv


#function below intended to iterate over key value pairs in csv file 
# after read in by dictionary reader 

def filter_the_dict(dictObj, callback):

    newDict = dict()

    # Iterate over all the items in dictionary

    for (key, value) in dictObj.items():

        if callback((key, value)):

            newDict[key] = value

    return newDict

#end of function call

# code below opens csv file using dictionary reader using headers as keys and
# rows underneath as pairs. Later I want to be able to filter for column or rows

with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('Test_colours_out.csv', 'w') as new_file:

        fieldnames = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:

            del line['Roll']

            newDict = filter_the_dict(csv_reader, lambda x: x[5] == 'Blue')

            print(newDict)

        csv_writer.writerow(newDict)

#****************************************
csv example file

Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import csv

with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('Test_colours_out.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        filtered = filter(lambda r: r['Name5'] == 'Blue', csv_reader)

        for row in filtered:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**Output**

```
Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
```

The key to solving the issue is the line:

```
filtered = filter(lambda r: r['Name5'] == 'Blue', csv_reader)
```

It creates an iterable, using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), with only the dictionaries (rows) that have `'Blue'` in the column `'Name5'`.